# Sublime text 3: Wanted cleared clipboard on copy

Tags: sublimetext3

What I want is to have my clipboard cleared when copying with nothing selected in Sublime text editor.

I have read up about the settings:

```
// If true, the copy and cut commands will operate on the current line
// when the selection is empty, rather than doing nothing.
"copy_with_empty_selection": true,
```

However I don't need either option. I want it to be cleared when nothing is found. The reason is I have an automated macro to perform searches and replaces if it finds something (and hopefully no changes if nothing found).

However the typical usage would copy the line, and if its the setting is turned off it copies what remained in the clipboard rather than overwriting with a blank.

Please help. 
Thanks

Comment: Tried `ctrl` + `shift` + `k`  ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `I want it to be cleared when nothing is found.`? Do you mean that if you don't have any text selected, doing a copy or cut, instead of doing a copy/cut operation, erases the contents of the clipboard and makes it empty instead?

Comment: @OdatNurd Yeah that was what I was hoping for. 

I found a work around by doing a shift right to grab an extra character so it doesn't copy the whole line. 
Anyways, we can close this query as I don't need it anymore. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Just for the record, it should be pretty simple to create a plugin  command that empties the clipboard and bind it to the copy key with a context that makes it take precedence when there is no selection, if that would be useful.